# C# Controller using MediatR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to setup a controller in C# using MediatR but my endpoint is not being hit.
Here's my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IMediator _mediator;

   public TestController(IMediator mediator)
   {
      _mediator = mediator;
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> TestReceiver([FromBody] User user)
   {
      return Accepted();
   }
}
```

My startup file

```
public class Startup : FunctionStartup //(will also be using AzureFunctions later)
{
   public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
   {
      builder.Services.AddMediatr(typeof(TestController).Assembly);
      builder.Services.AddControllers();
   }
}
```

When I test this in postman using the following link:(x is replaced my numbers of course)

POST: http://localhost:xxxx/api/test

It returns a 404.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

MediatR is not changing your API endpoints or routing so the issue is not here.

The most common mistake is to provide wrong body (not matching to your User model) when you are making POST requests (URL seems ok as long as you are using correct port) - web api is not able to match your request and returning 404.

If not, check if you have proper routing configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

this error is not related to MediatR. You may have an error in postman api-call.
Use postman like this:

1- url: http://localhost:xxxx/api/test

2- method: POST
body:

- raw
- mediaType: JSON (from the combobox located at the end)
- content: (json object of the user model like):  {"Name": "test"}

Note: I assumed that your user  entity has an attribute named "Name".